# Sloped border for Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I achieve this design with HTML and CSS? I need a sloped right border while maintaining the left background image + content (the purple grid) and the background image on the right side grid.  Here's how it should look like:

[image]

and this is what I've gotten so far :(

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 left">
        <h4>Q3 content</h4>
        <p>Ugit ut remporat utem aut poriorem. Tem reptium ium inumquam verum asi ut odio. Ped que senturi berspient harios doluptaquate re dellectatis imint, nimoloreste si idus, te reria velibusVelluptur sendus. Emolecti acid modiscipsam untetum esequunt es siminti uscipsandi dolent min rem aut exped moleseniam reprem et quamus mintur andipsa ndiaessuntem qui aut lacerspit, cumquiant et aut reiciis et autem rehento il est, sequi dio qui ommo te rem utemLectatem. Nam reperna turion nullest aut ea none net eatio qui cum nus aliquodi omnis</p>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.container .row { }
.left {
  background-color: #4D316B;
  color: #fff;
 }
.left:after {
   position: absolute;
        z-index: 20;
        content: "";
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        background: #F8BE15;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
        -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
        transform: skewX(20deg);
 }
.right {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
}
```

It doesn't have to be right border of the left grid, it can be any code format as long as it's mobile-responsive (the sloped border can change to a simple bottom or top border on mobile when the grids are stacked).

Here is [**how it looks now**](https://codepen.io/wpdevops/pen/vYKOKgm). A new pen would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I will be you, I would try to set the whole background with `linear-gradient` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: I'm not sure I am following how linear-gradient applies to this. I can create a large background photo and make the whole thing as one column but that's not ideal specially when the background photo resizes on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach: Natural order layering instead of `z-index`, and `overflow: hidden` masking.

https://codepen.io/ouroborus/pen/OJXVRgY

```css
.use-background {
    position: relative;
}
.use-background .background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.use-background .background *, 
.use-background .background *::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.use-background .background .left {
}
.use-background .background .left::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #4D316B url() center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.use-background .background .right {
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 20px #F8BE15 solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}
.use-background .background .right::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    background: #888 url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row use-background">
        <div class="background">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 left">
            <h4>Q3 content</h4>
            <p>Ugit ut remporat utem aut poriorem. Tem reptium ium inumquam verum asi ut odio. Ped que senturi berspient harios doluptaquate re dellectatis imint, nimoloreste si idus, te reria velibusVelluptur sendus. Emolecti acid modiscipsam untetum esequunt es siminti uscipsandi dolent min rem aut exped moleseniam reprem et quamus mintur andipsa ndiaessuntem qui aut lacerspit, cumquiant et aut reiciis et autem rehento il est, sequi dio qui ommo te rem utemLectatem. Nam reperna turion nullest aut ea none net eatio qui cum nus aliquodi omnis</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great! I have two question, 1) Any insights for making it mobile-responsive? I don't need the sloped border when the grids are stacked. A simple purple grid on top and the picture at the bottom would do. 2) I can't seem to find a way to apply the dark background logo to the purple grid to match the design. Applying the logo to "col-sm-6 left" doesn't extend it all the way to the right side of the grid. Thank you!

Comment: The relevant part just fills its container, in this case, the `.row` element. Making things responsive usually involves setting up different layouts in CSS using `@media`. There's an empty `url()` waiting for a background image that would end up in the left portion.

Comment: thank you for the effort, also thanks to Juan Herman for the initial answer.

Comment: me again, i'm having a hard time splitting these two grids to display as two stacked grids on mobile using media queries :( any insights or code sample on that?  Also, it turns out the image on the right hand side will be generated dynamically by the CMS, as of now it's placed as an static background for a pseudo element in CSS, is there a way to move that to HTML and use an img tag instead of a bg image for a pseudo?

Comment: That seems outside the scope of your original question. If you're having a specific issue, start another question (and feel free to refer back to this one). Don't forget to include what you've tried and so that the community can better help you.

Comment: not sure how it's outside of the scope since it was mentioned in the original question that it has to be mobile-responsive and stacked on mobile

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps change the order of the content and using bootstrap `order-` classes to change the presentation order of the elements. Instead of using the background for the yellow stripe, use a purple background and a yellow right border.

I have not considered responsiveness for other viewports.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 order-md-6 right">
        
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 left">
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Q3 content</h4>
        <p>Ugit ut remporat utem aut poriorem. Tem reptium ium inumquam verum asi ut odio. Ped que senturi berspient harios doluptaquate re dellectatis imint, nimoloreste si idus, te reria velibusVelluptur sendus. Emolecti acid modiscipsam untetum esequunt es siminti uscipsandi dolent min rem aut exped moleseniam reprem et quamus mintur andipsa ndiaessuntem qui aut lacerspit, cumquiant et aut reiciis et autem rehento il est, sequi dio qui ommo te rem utemLectatem. Nam reperna turion nullest aut ea none net eatio qui cum nus aliquodi omnis</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container .row { }
.left {
  background-color: #4D316B;
  color: #fff;

 }
.left .content {
  position: relative;
}
.left:before {
   position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        content: "";
        right: -60px;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        border-right: 20px solid #F8BE15;
  background: #4D316B;
  width: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
        -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
        transform: skewX(20deg);
 }
.right {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
}
```

https://codepen.io/juanherman/pen/WNxvGON

Comment: hey Juan, this is perfect. I am assuming adding a background image to the purple grid is not a problem, just like the design, right?

Comment: I missed that logo on the purple background. In that case The answer left by Ouroborus should work for that scenario.

Comment: Thank you Juan, really appreciate it. I changed the answer to Ouroborus.